# .d file not generating on Jenkins

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, dependencies

I just moved a couple of controller files from one group to another group and build the project on XCode. Everything works fine locally, but on Jenkins I am getting a build failure because .d file is not getting generated for one of the controllers. Its generating .d for other controller files I moved along with this one.

***ERROR:***

> Failed to load dependencies output contents from
>   ``/Users/ios/build/jenkins/workspace/my-group/intermediate/Group.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyController.d''.
>   Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file
>   “MyController.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no
>   such file." UserInfo=0x7faa5939b840
>   {NSFilePath=/Users/ios/build/jenkins/workspace/my-group/intermediate/Group.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyController.d,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x7faa59391050 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   No such file or directory"}. User info: {
>       NSFilePath = "/Users/ios/build/jenkins/workspace/my-group/intermediate/Group.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyController.d";
>       NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\""; }.

***Question:***
When and how does .d file get generated? I am trying to understand if I missed something while moving the files from one group to another.